# React: The Following code reset the state of the Counter component even though the Returned JSX Structure is not changed from the component

Tags: reactjs

In the Following code, the Scoreboard component is returning JSX. In the JSX we have a div inside that we have a Counter  Component.
Based on the value of isPlayerA state, the Counter is selected.

Even though the JSX returned from the Component has the structure of

```
<div>
    <Counter />
    <button>
</div>
```

Why the State getting destroyed?
Does '{}' curly braces cause the component to render at different position?

**Code Source** : https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state.

Section : Option 1: Rendering a component in different positions

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Scoreboard() {
  const [isPlayerA, setIsPlayerA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Taylor" />
      }
      {!isPlayerA &&
        <Counter person="Sarah" />
      }
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsPlayerA(!isPlayerA);
      }}>
        Next player!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ person }) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  let className = 'counter';
  if (hover) {
    className += ' hover';
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onPointerEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onPointerLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <h1>{person}'s score: {score}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setScore(score + 1)}>
        Add one
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `{test && <Component />}` is a javascript expression. The expression is evaluated on every render, and when the test fails, the component is unmounted - it ceases to exist.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems like Scoreboard is the appropriate place to store the score state. Then the Counter component is dumb enough to be ephemeral.